# Make Ng2-select show list after typing a minimum of 3 characters

Tags: angular, autocomplete, ng2-bootstrap

I need [ng2-select](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select) to give me a list of items with the ability to type and filter the list, an auto-complete function.

The problem is that my list is too big (+1000 items), so my idea is to show it only after typing a minimum of 3 characters so that the list is reduced.

If there is a lighter weight auto-complete field, I'm open for them too.

Comment: you need autocomplete component

Answer (score 0):

There's [ng2-auto-complete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-auto-complete) component that you can install with npm. Then you can configure in to use

> **min-chars**, number, when source is remote data, the number of character to see dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

you can set your items to be empty until your condition (3 characters) is met.
so you will have something like this:

```
completeItems: Array<string> = []; //your 1k+ list
items: Array<string> = []; //reduced list of items to show

public search(searchString: string) {
    if(searchString.length>2){ //3 character minimum
        this.items = this.completeItems;
    }
    else{
        this.items = [];
    }
}
```

and your ng-select:

```
<ng-select
    [items]="items"
    (typed)="search($event)"
    (data)="refreshValue($event)"
    (selected)="selected($event)"
    (removed)="removed($event)">
</ng-select>
```

have some issues when deleting characters, but is something.